# Visual Studio 2019 how to open the default tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to open all the default tabs that should be open when you open Visual Studio 2019 in the first place?

[image]

I'm having problems finding a tutorial about opening the essential tabs to make a form application.

Comment: You don't need any tabs to create a project. You have the File menu, and New - Project in there. You also have Tools - Options - Environment - Startup to control what you see when VS starts. The "Empty environment" is a good clean choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to open the tabs you have to go to "file- new project" then will appear the tabs to write the code
after that you can find all the tabs in the menu like option etc...